# The complements of supports of Cartier divisors of complex manifolds

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $D$ be a Cartier divisor of a complex manifold $M$ represented by $ \{ (U_i, \phi_i) \} $ where every $\phi_i$ is a meromorphic function on $U_i$ written as the ratio of holomorphic functions on $U_i$ : $\alpha_i / \beta_i$.

Suppose that every germ of $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$ are co-prime at each point of $U_i$.

Then $ \overline{M - |D|} = M $, where $|D|$ is the support of M?

Comment: In other words, the support of a Cartier divisor is nowhere dense. Do you have any tools, e.g., an identity theorem for analytic functions, or a local structure theorem about zero sets of holomorphic functions?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I understand the identity theorem. Does the local structure theorem claim that the zero sets of holomorphic functions connected?

Comment: The zero set of a holomorphic function is locally connected, but I was thinking along the lines of the [Weierstrass preparation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_preparation_theorem), that the zero set of a holomorphic function is locally a branched cover over a polydisk.

Comment: I only know the statement of the Weierstrass' theorem about the Weierstrass polynomials.